# How to save transformToDocument() return in new file?

Tags: xml, xslt

How can i save `transformToDocument()` returned new xml file and download it.

have this **code**.

```
result = new XSLTProcessor();
result.importStylesheet(xsl);
result = result.transformToDocument(xml);
```

if i use `document.write(result.childNodes.length);` it works fine.

**Problem** - but i need to save my Transformed xml file to system.

please help me out.

Comment: You need to provide more details, usually Javascript used inside the browser does not have permission to write to the local file system of the client the browser runs on. If you want to send the XML to the server use XMLHttpRequest e.g. var proc = new XSLTProcessor(); proc.importStylesheet(xsl); var resultDoc = proc.transformToDocument(xml); var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); req.open('POST', 'save.php'); req.send(resultDoc);`

Comment: If you use Javascript in a Firefox extension you should have access to the file system, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML#Serializing_DOM_trees_to_files